# Rescale data to match at specific peak?

Tags: r

This might be more of a math question than an R question.

Is there a way to rescale data so it matches at a specific point?

Here's an example:

```
peak_a<-c(0.1,0.4,0.6,0.8,0.9,1,0.9,0.8,0.6,0.4,0.1,0.05,0.04)
peak_b<-c(0.04,0.06,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.45,0.7,0.9,1.1,1.3,1.35,1.3,1.15,1,0.85,0.65,0.5)
abs<-c(peak_a,1.5*peak_b)
abs2<-c(1.5*peak_a,0.5*0.9*peak_b)
abs3<-c(0.9*peak_a,peak_b)
plot(abs, type="l")
lines(abs2,col="red")
lines(abs3,col="blue")
```

[image: Graph of three curves with two peaks each]
I want all three curves to have the same height at Peak A, while maintaining the ratio between Peak A and B. 
In my real data I have ca. 100 spectra with five peaks each. The peaks are always in the same range of x-axis values, and I want to rescale them for each peak while maintaining the correct ratios between all these peaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could scale each line by by a ratio at a point of the lines like this:

```
peak_a<-c(0.1,0.4,0.6,0.8,0.9,1,0.9,0.8,0.6,0.4,0.1,0.05,0.04)
peak_b<-c(0.04,0.06,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.45,0.7,0.9,1.1,1.3,1.35,1.3,1.15,1,0.85,0.65,0.5)
abs<-c(peak_a,1.5*peak_b)
abs2<-c(1.5*peak_a,0.5*0.9*peak_b)
abs3<-c(0.9*peak_a,peak_b)
plot(abs, type="l")
lines(abs2*abs[6]/abs2[6],col="red")
lines(abs3*abs[6]/abs3[6],col="blue")
```

[image]

some actual data from a couple of your curves might help to make a more robust solution more to your needs.

---

Here is a way of "automating" the procedure since you said you have many curves:

```
peak_a<-c(0.1,0.4,0.6,0.8,0.9,1,0.9,0.8,0.6,0.4,0.1,0.05,0.04)
peak_b<-c(0.04,0.06,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.45,0.7,0.9,1.1,1.3,1.35,1.3,1.15,1,0.85,0.65,0.5)
abs<-c(peak_a,1.5*peak_b)
abs2<-c(1.5*peak_a,0.5*0.9*peak_b)
abs3<-c(0.9*peak_a,peak_b)
abs4<-c(0.75*peak_a,peak_b)
abs5<-c(0.88*peak_a,peak_b)

plot(abs, type="l")

ListOfCurves <- sapply(2:5, function(x) paste0("abs",x))
AllCurves <- lapply(ListOfCurves, function(x) eval(parse(text=x)))
NormalizedCurves <- lapply(AllCurves, function (x) x*abs[6]/x[6])

lapply(1:4, function(x) lines(NormalizedCurves[[x]],col=x))
```

[image]